# Visual Studio 2015 Crashes on Startup

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

**Background**

I'm use to VS2015 for 'usual' C# development and I tried installing the other components to do Android development. VS2015 was working correctly before.

**Current situation**

When I start VS2015, it takes 5-10secs to load, then the IDE opens and is responsive (if I hover over any icons, the cursor changes and the icon highlights), and about 2-3 seconds later, VS crashes.

**Other Informations**

Running Windows 10 fully updated and it's the the Professional edition of Visual Studio 2015, with Update 1.

**What I've tried**

- Start as Administrator
- Repair Installation
- /Log
- /SafeMode
- /ResetSettings
- /ResetUserData
- /ResetSkipPkgs
- /ResetAddin
- Reinstalled VS (after doing the uninstall and the /force to clear everything.

At some point, in the ActivityLog.xml, I saw this, but it's unlikely that it would cause that hard of a crash:

```
<entry>
    <record>290</record>
    <time>2016/03/17 05:50:36.982</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.Extensions&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\OFLEGIJX.2GJ\...</description>
    <path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TEAMFOUNDATION\TEAM EXPLORER\</path>
</entry>
```

Anyways, I uninstalled it with a VSIXInstaller.exe command. Still does the problem.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: I thought about installing Update 2 RC, as someone else with a similar issue did, but I'm wondering why it's not working now, and it was before. I'll try it soon unless someone suggests something else.

Comment: try the update2, this fixed the issue for the user in the dup link

Comment: The update has been in the process since, but I haven't unchecked every other components like the other OP as in it wouldn't solve the issue for me cause I need the other components.

Comment: Worked! Yay! Thanks for pushing me to update magicandre1981!